# Problems after changing from saxon 9 enterprise to home edition

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

We have used saxon enterprise editon. Now we no longer have the license and because of this I had to remove a jar file (saxon9ee) from an application.

When I removed this jar file and added a saxon9-he, one of our functions stopped working. We have a link that creates a xml file with products and 
then publish this in html on the website. The xml file is still created but the publishing part is failing. It just shows a blank page instead.

As soon as I add the saxon9ee, it works again. But we can no longer use this jar - file.

Because of this I guess it has something to do with the transformation of the DOMSource (XSLT?) but I can not 
figure out what part is failing due to the loss of Saxon9ee. I get no exceptions. Is there any good way
to replace the functionallity that I lost from removing saxon enterprise edition?

The code:

```
public String publishXmlFile(AS400 as400) {
        try {

            init();

            build();

            CatalogListController ac = (CatalogListController) FacesUtils.getManagedBean(BeanNames.CATALOG_LIST_CONTROLLER);
            Catalog catalog = new Catalog(ac.getSelectedCatalog().getCatalogUi());
            addCatalog(catalog);

            String ifsPath = ApplicationProperties.getString("AS400ExportPath") + "internal/";

            String fileName = ifsPath + ac.getSelectedCatalog().getUrlCode() + ".xml";

            IFSFile xmlFile = new IFSFile(as400, fileName);


            if (!xmlFile.exists()) {
                xmlFile.createNewFile();
            }

            if (xmlFile.exists()) {
                xmlFile.setCCSID(1208);
                IFSFileOutputStream fos;

                try {

                    fos = new IFSFileOutputStream(xmlFile);

                    // Prepare the DOM document for writing
                    Source source = new DOMSource(document);

                    // Prepare the output file

                    Result result = new StreamResult(fos);

                    // Write the DOM document to the file
                    Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                    xformer.setOutputProperty("encoding", "utf-8");
                    xformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

                    xformer.transform(source, result);

                    System.out.println(source.toString() + " " + result.toString());

                    System.out.println("XML-FILE: " + xmlFile.toString());

                    fos.close();

                    xmlFile = null;
                } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TransformerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println(xmlFile.getAbsolutePath() + " ");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

intit() function:

```
private void init() {
    // Setup Doc
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        document = builder.newDocument();
        document.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ");
        domRoot = (Element) document.createElement("xKml");
        document.appendChild(domRoot);
        domRoot.setAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation",  "urn:company:xKml:2:0 http://www99.company.com/schemas/xKml-2-0/xKml-2-0.xsd");
        domRoot.setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        //domRoot.setAttribute("xmlns:xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        domRoot.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:company:xKml:2:0");

        timeFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

xsd file (http://www99.company.com/schemas/xKml-2-0/xKml-2-0.xsd):

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:company:xKml:2:0" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="2:0">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="../xKml-2-0-1/common/xKml-Components-2-0-1.xsd"/>

    <!--xsd:include schemaLocation="common/xKml-CommonComponents-2-0.xsd"/
    -->

    <xsd:include schemaLocation="../xKml-2-0-1/Order-2-0-1.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="../xKml-2-0-1/Invoice-2-0-1.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="../xKml-2-0-1/Catalog-2-0-1.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="../xKml-2-0-1/PurchaseForecast-2-0-1.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="../xKml-2-0-1/OrderResponse-2-0-1.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="../xKml-2-0-1/OrderChanges-2-0-1.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="../xKml-2-0-1/ControlMessage-2-0-1.xsd"/>

    <!--

    <xsd:include schemaLocation="documents/xKml-OrderDocument-2-0.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="documents/xKml-InvoiceDocument-2-0.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="documents/xKml-CatalogDocument-2-0.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="documents/xKml-PurchaseForecastDocument-2-0.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="documents/xKml-OrderResponseDocument-2-0.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="documents/xKml-OrderChangesDocument-2-0.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="common/xKml-ControlWorkdataMessages-2-0.xsd"/>

--><!--                 -->
<!-- xKml   -->
<!--                    -->
<xsd:element name="xKml">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="Version"/>
            <xsd:element ref="History"/>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element ref="Parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xsd:element ref="Interchange"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Documents">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:choice>
                                    <xsd:element ref="Catalog" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                    <xsd:element ref="PurchaseForecast" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                    <xsd:element ref="Order" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                    <xsd:element ref="OrderResponse" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                    <xsd:element ref="OrderChanges" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                    <xsd:element ref="Invoice" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                </xsd:choice>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="ControlMessage"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

build() function:

```
private void build() {
        Element e, e1, e2, e3;

        // basic sceleton for DOMtree
        e = (Element) document.createElement("Version");
        e.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:company:xKml:2:0");
        domRoot.appendChild(e);
        e.appendChild(document.createTextNode("02.00"));

        e = (Element) document.createElement("History");
        e.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:company:xKml:2:0");
        domRoot.appendChild(e);

        e1 = document.createElement("HistoryRecord");
        e1.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:company:xKml:2:0");
        e.appendChild(e1);

        e2 = document.createElement("Process");
        e2.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:company:xKml:2:0");
        e1.appendChild(e2);
        e2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("B2B"));

        e2 = document.createElement("Timestamp");
        e2.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:company:xKml:2:0");
        e1.appendChild(e2);

        e3 = document.createElement("Date");
        e3.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:company:xKml:2:0");
        e2.appendChild(e3);
        e3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dateFormatter.format(new Date())));

        e3 = document.createElement("Time");
        e3.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:company:xKml:2:0");
        e2.appendChild(e3);
        e3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(timeFormatter.format(new Date())));

        e = (Element) document.createElement("Interchange");
        e.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:company:xKml:2:0");
        domRoot.appendChild(e);

        e1 = document.createElement("InterchangeIdentity");
        e1.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:company:xKml:2:0");
        e.appendChild(e1);
        e1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dateFormatter.format(new Date()) + " "  + timeFormatter.format(new Date())));

        e1 = document.createElement("Timestamp");
        e1.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:company:xKml:2:0");
        e.appendChild(e1);

        e2 = document.createElement("Date");
        e2.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:company:xKml:2:0");
        e1.appendChild(e2);
        e2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dateFormatter.format(new Date())));

        e2 = document.createElement("Time");
        e2.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:company:xKml:2:0");
        e1.appendChild(e2);
        e2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(timeFormatter.format(new Date())));

        e1 = document.createElement("ComPartners");
        e1.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:company:xKml:2:0");
        e.appendChild(e1);

        e2 = document.createElement("From");
        e2.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:company:xKml:2:0");
        e1.appendChild(e2);

        e2 = document.createElement("To");
        e2.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:company:xKml:2:0");
        e1.appendChild(e2);

        e1 = document.createElement("DeploymentMode");
        e1.setAttribute("xmlns", "urn:company:xKml:2:0");
        e.appendChild(e1);

        e1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Operational"));


    }
```

addCatalog() uses the same methods and standards as build().

In the application version where it works I have these jars:

```
saxon9-icu.jar
saxon9-sql.jar
saxon9-stats.jar
saxon9ee-test.jar
saxon9ee.jar
saxon-license.lic
```

In the version without the enterprise that does not work:

```
saxon9-dom.jar
saxon9-icu.jar
saxon9-sql.jar
saxon9-stats.jar
saxon9-test.jar
saxon9-xqj.jar
saxon9.jar
saxon9he.jar
```

What do I have to do to replace the functionallity from saxon that is missing? And which part is it?

Thank you

Comment: Well which error(s) exactly do you get? As far as I know Saxon HE does allow you to transform a DOMSource so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I get no errrors. The page just turns out blank without the enterprise edition. I guess I need some specific functionality from the enterprise - jar file but I can not figure out exactly what or how to replace it. Home edition supports XSLT 2.0 but not 3.0 as the enterprise. Could this be the problem and how would be the best way to work around this? Is there any other XSLT processor that supports 3.0 if this is the problem? I did not code this application and because of this I do not know the code that well. Thank you

Comment: But `Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();` does not even load a stylesheet but only creates a default transformer to serialize a source so I don't see why Saxon HE or even the JRE's built-in Xalan should not be able to do that.

Comment: Yep, this is why I can not figure out which part from the Saxon9ee that does the work :) Since it works as soon as I add the Saxon9ee - jar file again. The creation of the xml-file works fine, because of this I can only guess that the reason has to be with the XSLT. Any other ideas what I should look for? Thank you

Comment: Is it possible that your XSLT is using Enterprise functions/features? Have you tried applying a simple identity transform to verify that it is loading and applying a very simple XSLT? Can you post your XSLT?

Comment: To be honest I do not realy get what you mean with posting the XSLT? I posted more information in my question. The XML file is built with some kind of XSD - schema and after this it is the XML Transformation (XSLT) processing from Saxon that is used to transform it into html? Or am I wrong here? These are the involved methods and the schema anyway. I would realy appreciate help. As I said before I did not code this application, have never used xml och xslt in this context before either,  and because of this I am lost here. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM code looks all wrong, you should use a namespace aware DOM factory/builder and then use namespace aware DOM methods like createElementNS and setAttributeNS.

Comment: Yep, this is the correct answer. I made the factory namespace aware and then I added namespaces to the elements. It wasnt needed for the attributes. But after this I tried it again, validated the xml and now it works. I have no idea why saxon enterprise supported it without namespaces. Thank you very much for all the help!

Comment: I've no idea either. Access to the DOM is something of a mystery. One of the worst things is that Saxon has no way of discovering whether the supplied DOM is namespace-aware or not, even though we need to know in order to access it correctly.